# Why is my chrome homepage looks so weird？

Tags: google-chrome

[image: When I type something in URL bar then press enter, this page shows up.]

It looks so weird, and did not search my keyword.

However, I can't find anything wrong in Chrome DevTools, what is happening here.

On Ubuntu this page does not have that header bar and input area has some box shadow

You can see two logos are not the same.

I thought I was hijacked by some sort of proxy server, but two computers are in the same exact Wi-Fi network.

When you type something in the location input bar then press <kbd>enter</kbd>, Chrome should automatically show search result for you.

But on my Mac Chrome, it just come to Google homepage then do nothing.

Comment: what is weird about it?  Is it because you re on google.com.hk ?

Comment: Please  edit your question , give more details .

Comment: @Filip same when using .sg or .jp    when I use ubuntu, it does not have that header bar, the entire style looks diffrent

Comment: What detail would you like to know? @GAD3R

Comment: @FrontMage The 2 pictures are the same. Looks like a normal google home page (HK). What's the thing that you don't like?

Comment: @User552853 stackoverflow won't let me add two different pics, when I use ubuntu it does not have that header bar.

Comment: @FrontMage: The one with your bookmarks ( Mac, Shell, MongoDB, etc.) or the one with the `Search > Images > Maps > etc` ?

Comment: @User552853 I combined two pics, the one with bookmark bar is on mac, the other is on ubuntu. Header bar I mean, Search > Images ....

Comment: @GAD3R I add some details, from the img I post, you can see the difference when using chrome on mac and ubuntu.

Comment: I can confirm that on my google chrome that link bar is not there either. It appears as if it is inserted somehow. Are you maybe running an add-in that could add this? You can figure out by disabling all addins and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: Also, make sure pinging to google.com.hk translates to 172.217.17.99

Comment: Are you trying to reset the settings from the advanced options of Settings?

Comment: @GAD3R nope. I didn't do anything

Comment: @LPChip when I ping google.com.hk, IP address turns out to be 93.46.8.89, but when I try to visit this IP in browser, it response nothing

Comment: @LPChip I googled this IP, it says this is some kind of DNS cache pollution, https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9F%9F%E5%90%8D%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8%E7%BC%93%E5%AD%98%E6%B1%A1%E6%9F%93, but I'm currently using a VPN located in Singapore

Comment: @FrontMage seems like you've found the cause. You can try an ipconfig /flushdns to see if it clears the dns cache and gets the proper ip. Also try disabling vpn

Comment: @LPChip Thanks man, been very helpful. But I have to connect VPN to visit google. Seems I have to find another way to do this. (sorry but flushing dns does not work)

Answer (score 0):

After trying to ping `google.com.hk`, instead getting response from [`172.217.17.99`](https://askdns.com/ip/172.217.17.99), I was redirected to [`93.46.8.89`](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9F%9F%E5%90%8D%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8%E7%BC%93%E5%AD%98%E6%B1%A1%E6%9F%93), which is some server in Italy.

According to Wikipedia, this IP was recorded as one of the victims of the Great Firewall.

This server seems to be some DNS cache server, and it’s been poisoned.

That’s why I was redirected to the old Google homepage.

This happens even if you're using VPN.